# Install Ubuntu on HP probook x360

Tags: grub2

I tried to install Ubuntu on the HP probook x360 Educational Edition, but GRUB fails to install on the HP probook x360

Answer (score 0):

Simple reboot using try Ubuntu mode and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then apply the recommended repair.

Comment: Running Boot Repair *per se* does nothing. Have you applied the recommend repair or some advanced option?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Absolutely, that's the point

Comment: On mine I get an "NVram locked" error message